# How can I see the payouts of this Ponzi scheme dapp?

Tags: dapps, gas, out-of-gas

Towards the very beginning of the Ethereum release, a friend participated in a Ponzi scheme dapp by sending 1 ETH [here](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xd43c16f7abd4e3cb60bc0f237b9c35db575cc5a87b3387088cac20256f39554a). He was among the first!

For some reason, it seems [he has not received any payout](https://etherscan.io/address/0xf3d688f06bbdbf50f9932c4145cbe48ecdf68904). Actually, the block explorers does not show any payouts, even though the [contracts balance](https://etherscan.io/address/0x109c4f2ccc82c4d77bde15f306707320294aea3f) is much lower than what it received.

How can I see the payouts of this Ponzi scheme dapp?

Comment: Related & worth a read: [What about illegal smart contracts](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/1013/87)? [Why is an account not accepting the Ether sent to it](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/642/87)?

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that he didn't send enough gas with his transaction. It looks like his transaction triggered a payout, and he wasn't expecting the increased gas costs.

See [live.ether.camp for the VM trace](https://live.ether.camp/transaction/d43c16f7abd4e3/vmtrace).